# Minimum dtsConfig properties for deployment

Tags: ssis

I am developing a SSIS package using BIDS 2008 which is for SQL Server 2008 R2.

I need to deploy my application in DEV and QA. What is the minimum properties needed in the dts config file for deployment.

At the moment what I can think of is just the connection string property and server name.

Comment: Build the first one manually from within SSIS. It will ask you to specify the property you want changed and allow you to specify a value. When you accept it, you will have an option to save the file. At that point, SSIS will create the XML dtsConfig file for you. You can then edit it in either notepad or through SSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection String and Server Name is all you minimally need.  Any other environmental difference depend on what your package does.

Comment: I am deploying to the database. Will only the connection string not be sufficient as it does contain the servername in the connection string

Comment: The connection string alone will be sufficient as long as you don't use the ServerName property in your package somewhere.